# SICStus Prolog: Convert domain to string

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying to solve the map colouring problem and below is the solution and it seems to work. However, the domains can be represented only in integer from 1 to 4. I would like to have them in strings though, e.g.

`colours: {blue, green, yellow, red}.` How can I do that? Below is the code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)). 
solve_AUSTRALIA(WA,NT,Q,SA,NSW,V):-
   domain([WA,NT,Q,SA,NSW,V], 1, 4),%colours represented by integers from 1 to 4
   WA #\= NT, 
   WA #\= SA, 
   NT #\= SA, 
   NT #\= Q, 
   SA #\= Q, 
   SA #\= NSW, 
   SA #\= V, 
   Q #\= NSW,
   NSW #\= V,
   labeling([],[WA,NT,Q,SA,NSW,V]).
```

Comment: There is no easy way to do so.

Comment: Don't know whether it is appropriate as it is not directly related  to the question but is there a way I can show all solution and/or find how much there is? I can only use ; to check through but this can be tiresome if there are so much to go through.